# Logical file System vs Physical file system

Tags: file, operating-system, filesystems

I was preparing for my operating end semester exam and got stucked at this topic. I searched a lot but didn't found the difference.

```
The difference between Logical file System and Physical file system
```

I know the difference between logical address and physical address but I think it doesn't have any relation with this.

Comment: The "logical file system" is the file system as it is in the OS's data structures at runtime. The "physical file system" is the the file system as it is arranged on physical storage. I'll try to post an answer sometime, ping me if I haven't done so in two weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer refers to physical vs logical blocks 
Files can consist of one or more records. A physical record (or physical block)
is the unit of information actually read from or written to a storage device. A logical
record (or logical block) is a collection of data treated as a unit by software. When
each physical record contains exactly one logical record, the file is said to consist of
unblocked records. When each physical record may contain several logical records,
the file is said to consist of blocked records.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that there is an error in the question. I imagine they are referring to logical disk I/O and physical disk I/O. File systems do not care which is used.

In ye old days, disk blocks were addressed physically. The OS had to request a block by specifying the platter, track, and sector.

In some cases, the OS would add a layer that would create a logical mapping of 0..N to physical blocks. Thus the operating system would translate a request for block X into a physical disk location (platter, track, sector). The OS would have to keep track of bad blocks and remap them.

Now, disks do this translation in hardware (although some disks allow physical I/O for diagnostics). The interface to the disk is logical I/O. The OS simply requests a logical block number and the hardware translates that into physical block location.

As disks move to solid state, physical disk I/O will disappear entirely.

Comment: The distinction logical and physical file system is not related to the translation between logical and physical block addresses in I/O.